# Having issue while upgrading rails from 4.x to 5.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having issues while upgrading rails versions. My ruby version is `2.6.3` and my current rail version is 4.2.1.
I tried with `rake rails:update` and `rails app:update`, but both of them gave me this error.

```
You have requested:
  rails = 5.0.7.2

The bundle currently has rails locked at 4.2.11.2.
Try running `bundle update rails`

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to `bundle update`
```

Trying what was suggested in the error gave me this error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    ancestry was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.2.0)

    annotate (~> 2.6.5) was resolved to 2.6.10, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.2, <= 4.3)

    globalize was resolved to 5.3.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.2, < 6.1)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      kaminari (>= 0.15, < 2.0) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends
on
          activerecord

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.0)

    activeadmin was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.4, which depends on
        activerecord (>= 3.0)

    seed_dump was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.0)

    active_admin-sortable_tree was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.2)
```

My end goal is to upgrade rails 4.x to 6.x. I am going step by step by upgrading rails 4.x to 5.x and then 5.x to 6.x. I am not able to achieve the first phase i.e upgrading 4.x to 5.x.
Any help regarding how can I solve this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you may have locked down some gems in Gemfile to versions that are incompatible with Rails 5.0.7.2. Suggest you remove the version constraints and let bundler find compatible versions. Start with the gems that are listed in the bundler error message.

Comment: @LesNightingill I tried by deleting the Gemfile.lock, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Are any of the gems mentioned in the error message constrained in Gemfile to be a certain version, or <= a specific version, or ~> a version? This is what I mean by having the gem versions perhaps locked to a version that's not compatible with Rails 5.0.7.2